# Print specific lines after a text present in another text file

Tags: linux, perl, text, printing

I have two text files. Text-file-1 contains strings (one string per line);

```
C 010
C 020
C 024
.
.
.
```

Text-file-2 contains data in following format;

```
C 005 Carbon
D Carbon 1
D Carbon 2
D Carbon 3
D Carbon 4
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 017 Oxygen
D Oxygen 1
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
.
.
.
```

Text-file-1 contains 30 lines but Text-file-2 contain huge data, and in the same format as I mentioned. I can grep the text in Text-file-2 found in Text-file-1 using following command;

```
awk 'NR==FNR { A[$2]=1; next }; A[$2]' Text-file-1 Text-file-2 > filename
```

Output for this script

```
C 010 Hydrogen
C 020 Nitrogen
C 024 Sulphur
.
.
.
```

My Desired output is;

```
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
.
.
.
```

Now, I need an extension of this command, which could print all lines (starting with "D"), including and after this line. All lines in Text-file-2 are starting with a letter (C or D). This letter is not useful for me, but I kept it. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, show the code and explain how it isn't working.

Comment: Nope. Actually Im newbie in programming. For this issue, I googled many websites, but could not find a solution.

Comment: @MuhammadSufian Then your goal is to learn programming first, then use your skills to attack this problem. Nobody here is interested in writing your code for you. I suggest you start with the [Perl Tutorial Hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/).

Comment: Ohkie friedo. Actually this was my first post to Stackoverflow. I will try my basic skills of linux commands on monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while read str; do sed -n "/^$str/,/^C/ {/^$str/p;/^D/p}" Text-file-2; done < Text-file-1
```

This is the sed command, contributed by steeldriver on another forum. And its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started. If you are a newbie, you probably need to learn some Perl, perhaps [Beginner's Introduction to Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html) is a good start. There is also the official [Perl Programming Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html). Happy programming!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $numbers, '<', \<<'EOF' or die $!;
010
020
024
EOF

open my $data, '<', \<<'EOF' or die $!;
C   005 Carbon
D     Carbon 1
D     Carbon 2
D     Carbon 3
D     Carbon 4
C   010 Hydrogen
D     Hydrogen 1
D     Hydrogen 2
C   017 Oxygen
D     Oxygen 1
C   020 Nitrogen
D     Nitrogen 1
D     Nitrogen 2
D     Nitrogen 3
C   024 Sulphur
D     Sulphur 1
D     Sulphur 2
EOF

my %want = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$numbers>;
my $number;
while (<$data>) {
    $number = $1 if /\A C \s+ ([0-9]{3})/x;
    print if $want{$number};
}
```

Output:

```
C   010 Hydrogen
D     Hydrogen 1
D     Hydrogen 2
C   020 Nitrogen
D     Nitrogen 1
D     Nitrogen 2
D     Nitrogen 3
C   024 Sulphur
D     Sulphur 1
D     Sulphur 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot chansen for the script. I will try it tomorrow in my lab, and then will let you know.

Comment: I have tried this script today, but it did not worked. Dont know the reason.Secondly, my data is different, and huge. I want to mention the text filename in the script, rather the data. I also worked on  the script in the link http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=756715, but it was too complex for me. @RobEarl